# mod_rewrite и регистр урлов

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:rFile} ^$
RewriteRule .? - [E=rFile:%{THE_REQUEST}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite uppercase letter URL to lowercase
# Skip next two rules if lowercasing in progress (Remove this rule if case-conversion plug-in below is removed)
RewriteCond %{ENV:qLow} ^yes$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=2]
# Prevent recursion and over-writing of myURI and myQS
RewriteCond %{ENV:qRed} ^yes$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [L]
# Get the client-requested full URI and full query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/[^?]*)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .? - [E=myURI:%1,E=myQS:%2]
# Uppercase to lowercase conversion plug-in (This section, along with the first noted rule above, 
# may be removed if not needed or wanted) Skip next 28 rules if no uppercase letters in URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ![A-Z]
RewriteRule .? - [S=28]
# Else swap them out, one at a time
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^A]*)A(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1a%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^B]*)B(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1b%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^C]*)C(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1c%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^D]*)D(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1d%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^E]*)E(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1e%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^F]*)F(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1f%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^G]*)G(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1g%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^H]*)H(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1h%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^I]*)I(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1i%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^J]*)J(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1j%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^K]*)K(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1k%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^L]*)L(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1l%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^M]*)M(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1m%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^N]*)N(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1n%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^O]*)O(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1o%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^P]*)P(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1p%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1q%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^R]*)R(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1r%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^S]*)S(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1s%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^T]*)T(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1t%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^U]*)U(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1u%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^V]*)V(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1v%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^W]*)W(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1w%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^X]*)X(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1x%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1y%2]
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1z%2]
# Set lowercasing-in-progress flag
RewriteRule . - [E=qLow:yes]
# If any uppercase characters remain, re-start mod_rewrite processing from the beginning
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . - [N]
# If any characters were lowercased, set redirect required flag and reset lowercasing-in-progress 
# flag (S=28 from above lands here)
RewriteCond %{ENV:qLow} ^yes$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [E=qRed:yes,E=qLow:done]
# End Uppercase to lowercase conversion plug-in
RewriteCond %{ENV:qRed} ^yes$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{ENV:myURI}%{ENV:myQS} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Есть данный код, призванный переводить все урлы в нижний регистр, с чем успешно справляется. Каким образом добавить условие, которое бы проверяло в конце существует ли файл в нижнем регистре и если не существует, то - RewriteRule на скрипт?

Замена `RewriteRule .? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{ENV:myURI}%{ENV:myQS} [R=301,L]` на

```
RewriteRule .? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{ENV:myURI}%{ENV:myQS} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index3.php?url=%{ENV:myURI} [L,QSA]
```

не приводит к нужному результату - существующие файлы mod_rewrite считает несуществующими. Имена всех файлов на сервере - в нижнем регистре. Переменная %{ENV:myURI} передается и представляет собой %{REQUEST_FILENAME} в нижнем регистре.

Comment: Вы вот написали про замену, но у вас срабатывает правило с флагом L `RewriteRule .? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{ENV:myURI}%{ENV:myQS} [R=301,L]` и ниже уже ни какие правила выполняться не будут.

Comment: Так 

RewriteRule .? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{ENV:myURI}%{ENV:myQS} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index3.php?url=%{ENV:myURI} [QSA]

то же самое