# Редирект на нижний регистр, кирилица

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс, редирект

Как сделать редирект в .htaccess на нижний регистр в URL с кирилицей?

Например, с

```
http://site.ru/Интернет/Магазин
```

на

```
http://site.ru/интернет/магазин
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/425398/186083 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444966/186083

Comment: Эти способы не работают с кирилицей, к сожалению. В любом случае, спасибо!